# Javascript: Why variable in global scope becomes property of its 'this' but it doesn't happen on variable inside functional scope for new object

Tags: javascript, namespaces, global-variables

When I run the following code on Chrome browser, I detect a different behavior between declaring a variable on global namespace and declaring a variable inside a functional namespace for a new object.

```
 1. var ss = 'text';
 2. console.log(this.ss);
 3. function Person(first){
 4.    console.log('inside');
 5.    console.log(this);
 6.    this.firstName = first;
 7.    var second = 'Qui';
 8.    console.log(this.second);
 9. }
10. var person1 = new Person('Leo');
```

On line 1, I declare variable `ss` and it becomes a property of `this` (global namespace = Window). I print `this.ss` on line 2 to confirm.

On line 7, I declare variable `second` but it doesn't become a property of its `this` (function namespace for Person object). On line 8, I print `this.second` which results undefined.

1. Why declaring a variable on global namespace makes that variable to become a property of `this`(global namespace = Window) ?
2. Why the behavior on item 1 does not happen inside a functional scope when creating a new object ?

Comment: That's just how JavaScript works. Global `var` declarations in browser JavaScript create `window` properties, while `var` declarations in function scope never create object properties.

Comment: Declaring a variable local to a function does not make it a property of the function object.

Comment: The global namespace is unique; your question is basically "why was JS designed this way?" The answer is "because that's how it was designed."

Comment: `global namespace = Window` thats it. You answered your own question...

Answer (score 0):

> Why declaring a variable on global namespace makes that variable to become a property of this(global namespace = Window) ?

Because `this` in the global scope is a reference to the object on which variables reside.

> Why the behavior on item 1 does not happen inside a functional scope when creating a new object ?

Because `this` in the function scope does not behave the same as it does in the global scope.

In a function that has a `this` binding, its value is determined by the caller of the function, and may be just about any object (or even a primitive in strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable local to a function does make it in-scope for that function but does not make it a property of the function object. When using the `this` keyword you are referencing the function as an `object` and can thus assign a variable to it as a property of that object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Everything you say is already part of the question. The OP is asking *why* it is that way.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the global scope is a reference to the object on which variables reside.

global namespace = Window. You said it yourself

In a function with `this` binding, its value is set by the caller of the function

further reading

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this